# Import CSV where header not top row

Tags: .net, excel, csv

I have a client where I import the data direct from a CSV however some of their Excel sheets start with say the company logo and generic text. These files are also sent to their third parties so we want to keep the format as it is.

I have been able to match the row title and import the CSV to Excel where the Name is on the first row, how can I 'look' on say Row 3?

I have removed most error handling for the posted code as it is long anyway!

```
Protected Sub btnExcelToSQL_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExcelToSQL.Click


    lblText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green
    lblText.Text = " "

    '#############  //'Check valid file type for photo

    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then

        Dim extension As String = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        If extension.ToLower() = ".xlsx" Or extension.ToLower() = ".xls" Then
            Dim vExtention As String
            vExtention = extension.ToLower
            'is okay
        Else

            'nothing to check
            lblText.Visible = True
            lblText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            lblText.Text = "Choose a file in that is one of the following types to upload. (xlsx - Excel File) "
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    '#############  \\'Check valid file type for the file

    Dim vFileName As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName
    Dim uploadFolder As String = "C:\sites\Examples\CSVUpload\UploadedExcel\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-m-yyyy-HH-mm-ss") + "_" + vFileName

    'We add a date to stop any files having the same name

    FileUpload1.SaveAs(uploadFolder)

    Dim excelConnectionString As String = (Convert.ToString("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=") & uploadFolder) + "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"

    '#### Upload, Rename and save file 
    '#### Open Excel to Parse here
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim oleda As New OleDbDataAdapter()
    Dim cmdExcel As New OleDbCommand()
    '#### End - Open Excel to Parse here


    Dim excelConnection As New OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)
    With cmdExcel
        .CommandText = "Select  [Unique Property Reference Number] from [Page 1$]" 'Names we want to select and the name of the sheet
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Connection = excelConnection
    End With
    excelConnection.Open()

    oleda = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmdExcel)
    oleda.Fill(ds, "dataExcel")

    If ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows.Count > 0 Then

        '#### Stored procedure details
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim commandSQL As New SqlCommand

        Dim ConnectionString As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SQLLocal").ToString()
        '########### End - Stored procedure details
        'Set date once 
        Dim vDate As Date
        vDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(0)

        connection = New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        connection.Open()

        'Dims for error handling and checking for invalid characters


        For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows.Count - 1 ' counted rows so loop through, ignores first row with names in 

            If (IsDBNull(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Unique Property Reference Number"))) Then
                'skip
            Else

                'Bring the data across, the rows(i)("xxx") must match a name on the Excel sheet but DOES NOT have to be in order
                With commandSQL
                    .Connection = connection
                    .CommandText = "spAddCSVDataLineAsbestos"  'Stored procedure here
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("UPRN", If(IsDBNull(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Unique Property Reference Number")), "", Trim(ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows(j)("Unique Property Reference Number"))))
                    .Parameters.AddWithValue("DateTimeAdded", vDate) ' Date set at start

                    .ExecuteNonQuery() 'Execute the query
                    .Dispose() 'dispose of the commandSQL
                    .Parameters.Clear() 'dispose of the Parameters, otherwise on the second loop we would still have the first Parameters live
                End With
            End If
        Next



        connection.Close() ' Close connection

        lblText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
        lblText.Text = "File Uploaded " & ds.Tables("dataExcel").Rows.Count & " Rows Successfully"



    Else
        lblText.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        lblText.Text = "File appears to be empty"

    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: CSV are pure text. Are you sure you're using CSV?

Comment: I am using XLS/XLSX files rather than CSV in this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Jet OLE DB 4.0 Provider allows you to use a range with a specific address. Use a dollar sign after the sheet name and concatenate the table range. For example: [Sheet1$A1:B10]
. In VB.NET do something like this:

```
  Private m_sConn1 As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
           "Data Source=C:\ExcelData1.xls;" & _
           "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"""
  Dim conn1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(m_sConn1)
  conn1.Open()
  Dim cmd1 As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * From [EmployeeData$A1:E100]", conn1)
  Dim rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader

  Debug.WriteLine(vbCrLf & "EmployeeData:" & vbCrLf & "=============")
  Do While rdr.Read()
     Debug.WriteLine(System.String.Format("{0,-10}{1, -15}{2}", _
        rdr.GetString(0), rdr.GetString(1), _
        rdr.GetDateTime(2).ToString("d")))
  Loop
  rdr.Close()
  conn1.Close()
```

Check this out:
[How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934)

Comment: That looks great, I will test it today and let you know how I get on!

Comment: Change my code to say: .CommandText = "Select * from [Page 1$A2:BB9999]" and it works! Thanks :-)